# HP ProLiant DL380 G7 LFF - Is every SAS HDD compatible?

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant, sas

I am just starting to get into server hardware, so please bear with me.

I bought a HP ProLiant DL380 Generation 7 with a LFF drive cage and I do not know which SAS drives are actually compatible. **Does every SAS drive work?**

In particular i found this cheap **IBM drive** on eBay (`IBM 45W7765 45W7766` with 3TB and 7200rpm) and would like to know if it will work with the DL380, or are there any limitations?

I checked the quick specs guide but it only mentions some HP drives.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use any SAS disk but hardware diagnostic features can fail (diodes panel) (my case with a 380G6)  therefore disks are OK in bios & operating system & performances are ok

Comment: @francoisP so the diode could light up but it wouldn't make any difference? Will raid work normally?

Comment: Exactly for lights ; And yes raid will work just as usual

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HPE HDDs will have custom firmware so "ordinary" HDDs even from OE HDD vendor will work just fine (and you'll even keep your warranty, please see my link below) but you won't have special features like health monitoring / LED indication working.

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-lpn11980

**Question**:
*Will adding third-party memory or disk drives void the warranty?*

**Answer:**
*Adding third-party memory or disk drives does not void the warranty. However, there are some implications when you need technical support. For example, when the memory used may relate to the problem you are experiencing, you will be asked to remove the third-party memory to confirm the problem still exists before a service provider is dispatched. HP does not cover on-site visits caused by third-party products, whether internal or external to the HP Netserver system processor unit.*

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason not to use HP disks here.

They're available and very [inexpensive on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-2TB-SAS-7-2K-3-5-HDD-Hard-Drive-508010-001-G7-Tray/183557397880?hash=item2abcdf9d78:g:k98AAOSw~gZcimQ8:sc:USPSPriority!60622!US!-1).

Comment: They are actually way more expensive here in Germany compared to third party drives.

Comment: You asked for advice. If you don't want problems, use HP disks and carriers.

Comment: @Sandrogo I would add, downtime always has a cost. If the disk fail as you didnt seen it was bad per the led in example and it take long to recover, how much you value that ? is it worth saving some bucks on the purchase is the actual question.

Comment: Brand new HP drives will have 3x markup over similar Seagate ones, but old stock and used ones are dirt cheap actually.